# WCF Authentication with Supporting Tokens over Non HTTP Transport

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I followed a guide, found here http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/03/26/authenticating-users-with-supporting-tokens-in-wcf-binding-extension.aspx for creating a security policy that meets my needs. I have it working as described in the article using a WCF HTTP transport.

However, I haven't been able to configure the customBinding for dealing with a non-Http transport such as plain WCF TCP. I keep getting the error message:

```
Binding 'CustomBinding' doesn't support creating any channel types. This often
indicates that the BindingElements in a CustomBinding have been stacked incorrectly 
or in the wrong order. A Transport is required at the bottom of the stack. The 
recommended order for BindingElements is: TransactionFlow, ReliableSession, 
Security, CompositeDuplex, OneWay, StreamSecurity, MessageEncoding, Transport.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for configuring the customBinding for using TCP transport?

Binding Example from Page:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="MutualCertificateBinding">
    <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"/>
    <httpTransport/>
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I did find this blog post http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/06/22/CustomTokensOverNonHTTPTransports.aspx about a potential solution, but it doesn't appear to work in this case as this uses message security and a streaming transport doesn't work the message security. Then if I change to 'buffered', I received the same error.

For Completeness: The problem I am solving is passing the user name of the logged on user from an ASP.NET MVC website to a WCF service that needs to know the user in order to only return data specific to that user.

EDIT: 
As Request, my binding configuration:
Working Http Client Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="MutualCertificate">
                <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" />
                <httpTransport/>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
        <trustedWeb>
            <binding name="MyTrustedWeb"
                     bindingReference="MutualCertificate" />
        </trustedWeb>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/DataServices/MyDataService"
                  binding="trustedWeb"
                  bindingConfiguration="MyTrustedWeb"
                  behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior"
                  contract = "IMyDataService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="MyDns" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate findValue="CN=ClientCert"
                                       storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                       storeName="My"
                                       x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <defaultCertificate findValue="CN=ServiceCert"
                                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                            storeName="My"
                                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                        <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck"
                                        certificateValidationMode="None" />
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
        <bindingExtensions>
            <add name="trustedWeb"
                 type="TrustedWebExtension.TrustedBindingCollectionElement, TrustedWebExtension"/>
        </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Working Http Service Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="MutualCertificate">
            <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" />
            <httpTransport />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
    <trustedWeb>
        <binding name="MyTrustedWeb"
                 bindingReference="MutualCertificate" />
    </trustedWeb>
</bindings>
<services>
    <!-- Use this service when testing with authentication, as you will need a custom client with username / password ability. -->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyDataServiceBehavior"
    name="MyDataService">
      <endpoint address="/DataServices/MyDataService"
                binding="trustedWeb"
                bindingConfiguration="MyTrustedWeb"
                contract="IMyDataService" >
          <identity>
              <dns value="MyDns"/>
          </identity>
      </endpoint>

      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses" />
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:30000"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>      
    <behavior name="MyDataServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        <serviceCredentials>
            <!-- <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
                                    membershipProviderName="SqlMembershipProvider" /> -->
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=ServiceCert"
                                storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                storeName="My"
                                x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
            <clientCertificate>
                <!-- <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" /> -->
                <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck"
                                certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TrustedWebExtension.UsernameBlankPasswordValidator, TrustedWebExtension"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
  <extensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
          <add name="trustedWeb"
               type="TrustedWebExtension.TrustedBindingCollectionElement, TrustedWebExtension"/>
      </bindingExtensions>
  </extensions>
```

Non Working TCP Service Side Config:
Change `<httpTransport/>` to `<tcpTransport />` and try to start the service. The Wcf Service Host throws the error above. I've tried a few variations on that theme of specifying more values for the transport and customBinding stack, but haven't been able to make anything work.

Comment: Show your binding configuration.

Comment: I've added the working configuration for http as well as the basics of what I changed for tcp in the original post.

Comment: I think this mode is not available for `netTcpTransport`. Try to use `MutualSslNegotiated` - that is the mode used by `netTcpBinding` with message security and client credentials type set to `Certificate`.

Comment: @Ladislav I believe you are correct that MutualCertificate won't work with a non HTTP binding. So thanks, at least I won't be barking up that tree any longer. However, I tried to change it to use `MutualSslNegotiated` and I still receive the same error. Any ideas? New Config: `<customBinding>
   <binding name="MutualSslNegotiated">
    <security authenticationMode="MutualSslNegotiated" />
    <tcpTransport />
   </binding>
  </customBinding>
  <trustedWeb>
   <binding name="MyTrustedWeb"
      bindingReference="MutualSslNegotiated" />
  </trustedWeb>`

Comment: I couldn't find anywhere using that security type to set message security or client certificate explicitly.